# Heroku won't detect pre-release differently package-sourced NuGet libraries on attempting to publish a .NET Core App

Tags: c#, heroku, .net-core, nuget, dsharp+

I've spend a good amount of time working on this .NET Core Discord bot using DSharpPlus and I want to host it on Heroku, at least for now.

To do that, I *only* ran the following commands in CMD:

```
heroku create --buildpack http://github.com/friism/dotnet-buildpack.git
git push heroku master
```

*(As you can see I'm using a third party build pack.)*

However, I am using the nightly 4.0 version of DSharpPlus, which is available on the package source `https://nuget.emzi0767.com/api/v3/index.json` instead of the default nuget `https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json`

This compiles and runs fine in Visual Studio and using `dotnet run`, however, upon doing `git push heroku master`, I get the following errors indicating it can't find the DSharpPlus libraries:

Unable to find package DSharpPlus with version (>= 4.0.0-nightly-00621)
- Found 38 version(s) in nuget.org [ Nearest version: 3.2.3 ]

**So in short, Heroku isn't detecting the prerelease non-default package sourced NuGet library I have, and is failing to push because of it.**

Comment: Do you have the feed https://nuget.emzi0767.com/api/v3/index.json on your nuget.config? This might happen when you have the extra feed on Visual Studio only (remote machine doesn't get it)